# Workflow Foundation: Do I use a Web Service or WCF - what's best for my WF?

Tags: wcf, web-services, workflow-foundation

I'm building a workflow app to investigate the technology.  I can't decide whether to go for a web service (and a technology with which I'm basically familiar) with WebServiceInputActivity's or WCF and ReceiveActivity's (and a new technology that I'll have to learn).

Are there any major reasons to go either way?

Clarification:

Are there any major (architectural) reasons relating specifically to WF to go either way?  I appreciate the input of the respondants, so far, but they focus on WCF rather than what the implications are for my workflow and its lifetime, maintainability, performance, expandability, etc. if I choose WebServices or WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WF and WCF are very much hand in hand in .net 4. I'd definitely suggest the latter.

Comment: Yes, I've read that.  But I've also read that WF was redesigned from the ground up and we'll basically have to start again if we want to go to WF4.  It seems it's at least six months away and everything I've found about it, so far, has been *&$&* videos.  You can't print videos out and take them on the train which is where I do most of my learning.  I hate them.  Grrr!  Whoops!  Rant over.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm having a good look at 4.0 right now. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt, it is [WCF](http://www.microsoft.com/net/WindowsCommunicationFoundation.aspx). [Migrating ASP.NET Web Services to WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730214.aspx)

> SUMMARY: Windows Communication
>   Foundation (WCF) provides a unified
>   framework for rapidly building
>   service-oriented applications that
>   makes it easy to build and consume
>   secure, reliable, and transacted Web
>   services. WCF’s single programming
>   model unifies the capabilities in
>   ASMX, WSE, Remoting, COM+, and MSMQ;
>   therefore developers need to learn
>   only one programming model.

Comment: Yeeees, but because it unifies the capabilites in ASMX, WSE, Remoting, COM+ and MSMQ it's five times bigger and more complicated than ASMX!  Okay, so I'm exaggerating but there does seem to be a lot more to it.  I'm plodding through Michele Leroux Bustamante's Learning WCF book but it looks like a long plod.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the others here that you should go with WCF.

Just thought to add one more point, that just because you use WCF does not mean that you cannot access existing web services. You can use a WCF client with basichttpbinding, to access existing non WCF web services.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a mistake to call ASMX web services "web services" and suggesting that WCF can't be used to make web services. A WCF service using `basicHttpBinding` is exactly like an old ASMX service.

The best reason to use WCF instead of ASMX is that Microsoft has now stated that ASMX is a "legacy technology", and that they will not be fixing bugs in it.

Comment: I know WCF can do web services but as I pointed out, there's a learning curve there: a lot of investment of time and money at the end of which I'll be able to do exactly what I can do now - the problem with MS and their capricious changes is that they don't know/understand/care what an idiot I look when I have to go to the board for money to do exactly what I can already do because they've changed their minds.  Grrrr.  Anyway, rant over.  That's still not an architectural reason.

Comment: There's really very little learning curve for a simple web service. Just try the basic "WCF Web Service Project" template and see how simple that is.